# database for robot in labyrinth

Tags: database, robotics

I need help with constructing a database for my project - robot in a labyrinth.

I have 4 tables:

- table concept (concepts like labyrinth, robot, field, sensor_ultrasound, sensor_colour, forward,rotate_right,rotate_left,wall,hole,finish,empty_space etc.)
- table sensor_values (it contains all sensor values that robot detects in the labyrinth)
- table labyrinth_rules (it contains all sensor values that robot detects in the labyrinth in a specific moment with attribute concept, eg: in moment 1, sensor_ultrasound has value 28, sensor_colour has value 3 -> it is a wall (id_concept)) and
- table robot_state(it contains robots coordinates and heading, id:concept and decision...example: in a moment 1, robot is in position x=1, y=2, heading 90°, concept:wall, decision:rotate left or right). Here is the picture of my database now...

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PjsH9.jpg

As you can see I have everything connected to my concept table because all my concepts are in there.

I need help with this: as you can see in table sensor_values I have hard coded the table because I have two sensors...but I have to make another table SENSOR that will have all sorts of sensors (so that user can in anytime insert new sensor) but I dont know how to adjust tables sensor_values and labyrinth_rules with it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to be able to add an arbitrary number of sensors. I also see some duplication of data here.  You might find this schema to be simpler.

```
* Concept
  - id
  - name

* SensorRules
  - sensor_id
  - concept_id
  - sensor_value

* SensorValues
  - id
  - TimeStep
  - Value

* RobotState
  - TimeStep
  - Position
  - Concept
  - Decision
```

You can query the database for which rules correspond to the set of sensor values you have.